# Can electromagnetic waves apply forces on matter?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Basically I want to know whether non-mechanical waves apply forces on matter?

Answer (score 6):

An electromagnetic (EM) wave is a particular realization of an electromagnetic field.  Just like other electric fields, the field in the wave can apply forces to charged particles.

This is partially how radio receivers work.  In a conductor like a radio antenna, the atomic nuclei and inner electrons are fixed in place, but some of the outer electrons in the atoms are free to move around. As the wave passes by the antenna, the electric field applies forces, moving the free electrons around.  The moving electrons are a time varying current that follows the time variations in the electric field due to the wave.

Electromagnetic waves can also apply forces in the direction they travel, since they have momentum.  This is called radiation pressure.